# Set subtraction while retaining order

Tags: python

I know with set subtraction I can do the following:

```
l2 = set([4,3,5,2])
l1 = set([3,8])
l2 - l1
set([2, 4, 5])
```

How would I do this same thing, while keeping the ordering in `l1`. For example:

```
l2 = [4,3,5,2] 
l1 [3,8]
# remove 3, keep other ordering
l2 - l1
[4,5,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 = [4,3,5,2]
l2 = [3]
# remove 3, keep other ordering
st = set(l2)

print([x for x in l1 if x not in st])

[4, 5, 2]
```

Just make `l2` a set and  use `in` keeping elements from `l1` that are not in `st`. set lookups are `0(1)` so you still have an efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks -- would there be a 'faster' way to do this? My two sets are about a million members long. The set subtraction was working quickly, but this list comprehension takes a few minutes.

Comment: if you have a million elements a generator expression would probably be a better idea unless you actually need a list, if you want to keep order  I cannot think of a much more efficient straight forward way. Using numpy might be a better idea

Comment: Are you sure there is such a difference? I don't see how it could take a few minutes

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This could easily take a very long time, since the comprehension is clearly (at least) O(n^2).

Comment: @h7r,  how is it quadratic? Do you know what `0(1)` means? Also something is either `n^2` or it's not . How could it be any more than `n^2` even  if it we did not use a set?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham do you know what average and worst cases are? https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @h7r, I still don't see how you reckon it could be any more than n^2 even simply using lists? To be `0(n)` all the keys would also need to have the same hash value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ignoring the inherent overhead of the list comprehension, for each `not in` lookup, done `n` times (`x in l1`), you have again up to `n'` steps. `n` times `n'` adds up to O(n^2).

Comment: @h7r, yes I understand the complexity of a double for loop  but you said at least `0(n^2)` I don't understand how it could be any worse?

Comment: What I meant with "at least" is the added time for the list comprehension, which are usually inefficient. Don't read that bit into the complexity discussion.

Comment: @h7r, I presumed you meant it could be `0(n^3)`, how is a list comprehension inefficient?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm lacking a reference for this now (would like myself), so I might be proven wrong, but I'm only aware of benefits (performance-wise) in plain comprehensions (that is, without condition). AFAIK having conditionals they don't get executed as a `map` + `filter` in this case. I have had such impressions in practice too. Nothing that I can prove now.

Comment: @h7r, as I understand it a list comprehension is faster because of the special   `LIST_APPEND` bytecode generated and avoiding the need to call the method append.  I would be surprised if it would be faster having to call a method using a for loop whether you had an if statement or not  would be as or more  efficient and timings suggest I am correct.